# Memory leaking for service passed to unloaded AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, appdomain

I am experiencing a memory leak in context with `AppDomains`. I've stripped it down to the following:

I got 3 projects, two library projects and a console project: Shared, `DynamicallyLoadable` and `RemotingTimeoutPrototype` (the console program). Shared contains interfaces used by both `DynamicallyLoadable` and `RemotingTimeoutPrototype`. Both reference Shared at compile-time. There are no other compile-time references between any of the projects.

Shared contains this:

```
public interface IHostService
{
    string GetStuff();
}
public interface IRemoteClass
{
    IHostService Alpha { get; set; }
    string CallHostServices();
}
```

DynamicallyLoaded contains only a single type:

```
public class RemoteClass : MarshalByRefObject, IRemoteClass
{
    public IHostService Alpha { get; set; }
    public string CallHostServices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Domain {0}, RemoteClass.CallHostServices():", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id);
        return Alpha.GetStuff();
    }
}
```

The console project contains an implementation of `IHostService`:

```
public class Alpha : MarshalByRefObject, IHostService
{
    readonly byte[] mBuffer = new byte[100*1024*1024];
    public Alpha()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < mBuffer.Length; ++i)
            mBuffer[i] = (byte) (i%256);
    }
    public string GetStuff()
    {
        return "Alpha";
    }
}
```

Program.Main consists of this:

```
while (true)
{
       var otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("OtherDomain");
       var proxy =
           (IRemoteClass)
            otherDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("../../../DynamicallyLoadable/bin/debug/DynamicallyLoadable.dll",
                        "DynamicallyLoadable.RemoteClass");
       var alpha = new Alpha();
       proxy.Alpha = alpha;
       Console.WriteLine(proxy.CallHostServices());
       Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
       AppDomain.Unload(otherDomain);
       RemotingServices.Disconnect(alpha); // this was just an attempt, doesn't change a thing whether it's there or not
       GC.Collect(); // same here, this shouldn't really be necessary, I just tried it out of despair
}
```

Now when I let this run for a while, memory consumption increases constantly and eventually I hit an OutOfMemoryException.

I would expect that if the domain holding the proxy is unloaded, then the proxy is unloaded, too, and there are no references to the concrete Alpha anymore, so this would be collected. But obviously it is not.

Note that I also checked that the domain is really being unloaded by referencing mscoree and enumerating the loaded domains with code along the lines of:

```
var runtimeHost = new CorRuntimeHost();
runtimeHost.EnumDomains(out handle);
// etc.
```

Also, if I attach a handler to otherDomain.DomainUnload(), this handler is called just fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a typical problem of blocked finalization thread (as you have while-loop in, probably, STA thread and never give control to another threads explicitly). Even though you unload/dispose the domain it might be in the memory because it is not finalised. Read more here: http://alexatnet.com/articles/memory-leaks-in-net-applications - specifically the section "Blocked Finalization Thread" (I'm the author)

Comment: I just read through your article. I will use WinDbg as per your description tomorrow (right now it's almost 2am where I live ;) to check whether I see any build up in "ready for finalization" objects. I wonder however what would be the fix in my case. Maybe relevant: the while loop is what my Main consists of, there is nothing more.

Comment: I just tried a simpler way of checking whether the proxied RemoteClass instance is being destroyed by adding a destructor to RemoteClass like this:         ~RemoteClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Being destroyed");
        }
- and I see the console message, thus the proxied instance is being destroyed. Which would defeat the finalizer theory, wouldn't it?

Comment: My guess that it is not the RemoteClass that should be destroyed/finalized in this thread, it is the proxy. Anyway, have you tried to add WaitForPendingFinalizers after GC.Collect?